GAS assembler: What are the uses of .type? (A set of questions)

When can I use this directive?

Are there any other types besides function, tls_objrct, object, and common?

Are there examples of using each type from the .type?

Can I create my own type and mark it in .type?


Why do this:
.type label_func, @function


If we ourselves know that we are calling a function, but not a variable.
https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Type.html

You know it, but the tools don't know it. This tells the tools. The available choices are listed in the manual (as you found). No you can't define your own.
